# DataValidation using Regex not working

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, xaml, validation

So I have a MaskedTextInput box as follows:

```
<telerik:RadMaskedTextInput Margin="2" BorderBrush="LightGray"
                            IsClearButtonVisible="False"
                            Mask="(###) ###-####"
                            UpdateValueEvent="PropertyChanged"
                            TextMode="PlainText"
                            Value="{Binding Path=PhoneNumber, 
                                            Mode=TwoWay, 
                                            NotifyOnValidationError=True, 
                                            ValidatesOnExceptions=True,
                                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

and it is bound through a ViewModel with the following code-behind:

```
//Phone Number
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = @"A phone number is required.")]
[RegularExpression(@"^\d{10}$", ErrorMessage = @"Invalid phone number.")]
public string PhoneNumber
{
    get { return _phoneNumber; }
    set
    {
        if (_phoneNumber!= value)
        {
            Validator.ValidateProperty(value, 
                new ValidationContext(this, null, null)
                {
                    MemberName = "PhoneNumber"
                });
            _phoneNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PhoneNumber");
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm attempting to do is when a user has anything other than 10 digits present to throw an exception causing the border to turn red.

It works fine for the other fields like the email address but for some reason it does not work for the phone number field with the mask set.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what does that mean?  Are you getting an error message?  Does it allow bad data through?  Does it block good data?

Comment: @David, Say it is blank and I type anything there is no red box (error). When it is prepopulated with digits and I subtract one or all. There is still no red box (error).

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radmaskedinput/features/validation/validation) from telerik you need to throw an exception in your set statement.

```
set
{
    if (_phoneNumber!= value)
    {
        // Do the validation and throw an validation exception.
        if(/*validation statements*/)
        {
          throw new ValidationException("........Error message..........");
        }
        _phoneNumber = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("PhoneNumber");
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the problem lies within the mask property, because whenever I set the mask to nothing and test with a simple 10 digit number it is valid and when I start deleting all the way to no digits it does as required. However, when I have the mask it doesn't work at all. My validation comes from Telerik as well (http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radmaskedinput/features/validation/regex).

Comment: The link you're referring to is for Silverlight controls. Though data annotation works as same as in WPF but still what is going on under the hood within Telerik control is still a mystery.

Comment: I posted the same question on the Telerik forums and they responded with the solution. There is a setting called AllowInvalidValues and it must be set to true. According to Telerik 'This ensures that the Setter of the property will be fired even if the DataAnnotaion Validation does not succeed - in your case the error message will be shown when the users start typing until they entered all 10 digits.' It works exactly as I needed.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired response I needed to set the `AllowInvalidValues` property of the MaskedTextInput to true:

```
<telerik:RadMaskedTextInput   AllowInvalidValues="True" .../>
```

This ensures that the Setter of the property will be fired even if the DataAnnotaion Validation does not succeed - in my case the error message will be shown when the users start typing until they entered all 10 digits.